# R How to permute all rows of a data frame such that all possible combinations of rows are returned in a list?

Tags: r, permutation

I'm trying to produce all possible row permutations of a data frame (or matrix if that's easier) and have an object returned as a list or array of the data frames/matrices. I've constructed a mock dataframe that as the same dimensions as the one I'm working with.

```
test.df <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:80,nrow=16,ncol=5)
```

Edit: changed combinations to permutations

Comment: 1) Problem not clearly defined.  Can there be more than two rows in a combination? 2) what did you try already? A simple google search for "combinations in R" would have given you pointers without posting a question here.

Comment: Did you mean combinations or permutations of the rows? For permutations, I gave an answer below.

Comment: I think you should clarify what you are asking, else the question will likely be closed.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion everyone. I corrected the post so that it should make more sense for any future readers. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
v.df <- data.frame(symbol = c("a", "b", "c"), number = c(1,2,3))
v.df
##   symbol number
## 1      a      1
## 2      b      2
## 3      c      3

permutate.rows <- function(df) {
  k <- dim(df)[1] # number of rows
  index.df <- as.data.frame(t(permutations(n = k, r = k, v = 1:k)))
  res <- lapply(index.df, function(idx) df[idx, , drop = FALSE])
}

permutate.rows(v.df)
```

gives the list of all permutated dfs:

```
$V1
  symbol number
1      a      1
2      b      2
3      c      3

$V2
  symbol number
1      a      1
3      c      3
2      b      2

$V3
  symbol number
2      b      2
1      a      1
3      c      3

$V4
  symbol number
2      b      2
3      c      3
1      a      1

$V5
  symbol number
3      c      3
1      a      1
2      b      2

$V6
  symbol number
3      c      3
2      b      2
1      a      1
```

Use 16 instead of 3 and your data frame to apply it on your example.

Comment: permutations are not the same as combinations

Comment: He wrote `combinations` but he meant `permutations` and he tagged it as `permutation`. Can you please remove the -1 flag?

Comment: not my -1.  BTW, from the help centre "Not all questions can or should be answered here." https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: okay thanks for pointing that. I was just annoyed, because I read carefully and tried to think out what he means ... yes, question is badly posted. But in itself it is a question which one can think about.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Sorry for the confusion from the typo in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

I shortened the df because 16!=20922789888000

```
library(purrr)
library(combinat)

test.df <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:25,nrow=5,ncol=5))

map(permn(1:nrow(test.df)), function(x) test.df[x,])
```